# Covariance of Random Variables and limit of empirical expected value

Tags: probability, limits, convergence-divergence, covariance

> Let $\{X_i\}$ be uncorrelated, identically distributed random variables with $\mathbb{E}[X_1]=0$ and $\mathbb{E}[X_1^2]=1.$ Given are
> $$
>   Y_k=\frac{1}{2} X_{k-1}+X_{k}, k\geq 0
>   $$
> and
> $$
>   S_n=Y_1+Y_2+...+Y_n, n\geq 1.
>   $$
> (a) Calculate $\operatorname{Cov}(Y_k, Y_{k+j})$ for $k\geq 0, j\geq 1$.
> (b) Show that for all $\varepsilon>0$.
> $$
>   \mathbb{P}\left(\left|\frac{S_n}{n}\right|\geq \varepsilon\right)\stackrel{n\rightarrow\infty}{\rightarrow}0.
>   $$

---

I got this far:
(a) We have
$$
  \begin{aligned}
 & \operatorname{Cov}(Y_k, Y_{k+j})=\mathbb{E}[Y_k Y_{k+j}]-\mathbb{E}[Y_k]\mathbb{E}[Y_{k+j}]\\
      &= \mathbb{E}\left[\left(\frac{1}{2} X_{k-1}+X_{k}\right)\left(\frac{1}{2} X_{k+j-1}+X_{k+j}\right)\right]-\mathbb{E}\left[\frac{1}{2} X_{k-1}+X_{k}\right]\mathbb{E}\left[\frac{1}{2} X_{k+j-1}+X_{k+j}\right]\\
      &=\mathbb{E}\left[\frac{1}{4}X_{k-1}X_{k+j-1}+\frac{1}{2}X_{k-1}X_{k+j}+\frac{1}{2} X_{k}X_{k+j-1}+X_{k}X_{k+j}\right]\\
      &-\left(\frac{1}{2}\mathbb{E}\left[ X_{k-1}\right]+\mathbb{E}\left[X_{k}\right]\right)\left(\frac{1}{2}\mathbb{E}\left[ X_{k+j-1}\right]+\mathbb{E}\left[X_{k+j}\right]\right)\\
  \end{aligned}
  $$
Because of the identical distribution, the expected values that are subtracted are equal to $0$, so that only
$$
  \frac{1}{4}\mathbb{E}\left[X_{k-1}X_{k+j-1}\right]+\frac{1}{2}\mathbb{E}\left[X_{k-1}X_{k+j}\right]+\frac{1}{2}\mathbb{E}\left[ X_{k}X_{k+j-1}\right]+\mathbb{E}\left[X_{k}X_{k+j}\right]
  $$
remain. How to continue from here?
(b)
With the Chebyshev inequality we get
$$
  \mathbb{P}\left(\left|\frac{S_n}{n}\right|\geq \varepsilon\right)\leq\frac{\operatorname{Var}\left(\frac{S_n}{n}\right)}{\varepsilon^2}=\frac{\operatorname{Var}\left(S_n\right)}{\varepsilon^2n^2}
  $$
Here I am also stuck. Hints would be great, thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can see that the covariance depends on $j$, that is
$$Cov(Y_k,Y_{k+j})=\frac{1}{4}\mathbb{E}\left[X_{k-1}X_{k+j-1}\right]+\frac{1}{2}\mathbb{E}\left[X_{k-1}X_{k+j}\right]+\frac{1}{2}\mathbb{E}\left[ X_{k}X_{k+j-1}\right]+\mathbb{E}\left[X_{k}X_{k+j}\right]$$
Since the random variables $X_i$ are uncorrelated, we get the following cases :

- If $j=0$ :
  $$Cov(Y_k,Y_{k})=\frac{1}{4}\mathbb{E}\left[X_{k-1}X_{k-1}\right]+\frac{1}{2}\mathbb{E}\left[X_{k-1}X_{k}\right]+\frac{1}{2}\mathbb{E}\left[ X_{k}X_{k-1}\right]+\mathbb{E}\left[X_{k}X_{k}\right]$$
  $$=\frac{1}{4}\mathbb{E}\left[X_{k-1}^2\right]+\mathbb{E}\left[X_{k}^2\right]=\frac{1}{4}+1=\frac{5}{4}$$
- If $j=1$ :
  $$Cov(Y_k,Y_{k+1})=\frac{1}{4}\mathbb{E}[X_{k-1}]\mathbb E[X_{k}]+\frac{1}{2}\mathbb{E}[X_{k-1}]\mathbb E[X_{k+1}]+\frac{1}{2}\mathbb{E}[X_{k}X_{k}]+\mathbb{E}[X_{k}]\mathbb E[X_{k+1}]$$
  $$=\frac{1}{2}\mathbb E[X_k^2]=\frac{1}{2} $$
- If $j>1$ :
  $$Cov(Y_k,Y_{k+j})=\frac{1}{4}\mathbb{E}[X_{k-1}]\mathbb E[X_{k+j-1}]+\frac{1}{2}\mathbb{E}[X_{k-1}]\mathbb E[X_{k+j}]+\frac{1}{2}\mathbb{E}[X_{k}]\mathbb E[X_{k+j-1}]+\mathbb{E}[X_{k}]\mathbb E[X_{k+j}]$$
  $$=0$$

We finally get
$$Cov(Y_k,Y_{k+j})=\frac{5}{4}\delta_0(j)+\frac{1}{2}\delta_1(j)$$
On the other hand,
$$Var(Yi)=Cov(Y_i,Y_i)=\frac{5}{4}$$
Which yields
$$Var(S_n)=\sum_{i=0}^n Var(Y_i)=\frac{5n}{4}$$
Using your inequality now yields
$$\mathbb P\left(\left|\frac{S_n}{n}\right|>\varepsilon\right)\leq \frac{Var(S_n)}{n^2\varepsilon^2}=\frac{5}{4n\varepsilon^2}\overset{n\rightarrow \infty}{\longrightarrow} 0$$
Finally
$$\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}\mathbb P\left(\left|\frac{S_n}{n}\right|>\varepsilon\right)=0$$

Comment: But how can we use independence if we only have that they are identically and uncorrelated?

Comment: Terminology mistake. Fixed. Yes you can deduce the expectation property from the random variables being uncorrelated.

Comment: I guess you still need to handle the $j = 1$ case for the covariance part, in addition to the $j = 0$ case. For $j \geq 2$, there will be no "overlap" between $Y_k$ and $Y_{k+j}$ (no common elements of $X$)

Comment: @BGM Right ! Didn't notice it.

Comment: Just one more minor thing: After incorporating the $j = 1$ terms, those $Y$ are no longer uncorrelated; You will need to consider the extra bi-diagonal terms in additional to the original diagonal terms of the covariance matrix of $Y$. But since adding those $2(n-1)$ covariances is still linear in $n$, it will not affect the final result.